# are .appspot google app engine sites restricted in crawl / search engine rankings?

Tags: google-app-engine, seo, search-engine

i'm not recieving any hits on sites with "*.appspot.com" addresses. I've set up google webmaster and everything. Are you required to have a custom domain to show up in google search indexes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom domain to show up in google search.

There are many examples of ranking sites, for example: https://www.google.de/#q=fix+the+road